# How to to get data from multiple endpoints using axios from firebase react native expo app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, axios

I am using firebase for my database. I can access firstBlock as I created first node in firebase. But I am not able to fetch data from secondBlock which is second node. I am new for react and react native.

[image]

//http

```
import axios from "axios";
const BACKEND_URL = "https://saint-eloy-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/";

export async function fetchData() {
  const response = await axios.get(BACKEND_URL + "firstBlock.json");
  const responseTwo = await axios.get(BACKEND_URL + "secondBlock.json");

  // Promise.all([response, responseTwo]).then((value) => {
  //   const response = value;
  // })

  const getFetchedData = [];

  for (const key in response.data) {
    const dataObj = {
      id: key,
      title: response.data[key].title,
      subTitle: response.data[key].subTitle,
      descriptionBlock: response.data[key].descriptionBlock,
    };

    getFetchedData.push(dataObj);
  }

  return getFetchedData;
}
```

//Camping
This is the file where I am fetching my data

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, ScrollView } from "react-native";
import color from "../app/color";
import variables from "../app/variables";
import { fetchData } from "../utils/https";

function Camping() {
  const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getFetchedData() {
      const getFetchedData = await fetchData();
      setFetchedData(getFetchedData);
    }
    getFetchedData();
  }, []);

  const content = fetchedData;

  return (
    <>
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{ marginBottom: 10, backgroundColor: "pink" }}>
          {content.map((item) => {
            return (
              <View key={item.id}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.subTitle}>{item.subTitle}</Text>
                {item.descriptionBlock &&
                  item.descriptionBlock.map((i) => {
                    return (
                      <View>
                        <Text style={[variables.bodyText, styles.description]}>
                          {i.paragraph}
                        </Text>
                      </View>
                    );
                  })}
              </View>
            );
          })}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </>
  );
}

export default Camping;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { marginBottom: 20 },
  title: {
    fontSize: 22,
    fontFamily: "robotoBold",
    color: color.primary,
    borderBottomColor: color.red,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    paddingBottom: 18,
    marginBottom: 30,
  },
  subTitle: {
    color: color.secondary,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontFamily: "robotoBold",
    marginBottom: 25,
  },

  description: {
    color: color.blackOne,
    marginBottom: 25,
  },

  descriptionBlock: {
    backgroundColor: "green",
  },
});
```

I want to fetch data from both first and second block. Please help